# HTML Button are being place under my text?

Tags: html, css

I have my HTML code:

```
<div class="container">

    <button onclick="IndexButton()" style="background: url(images/viewmessages.png);"/>

    <h1>Post a Message</h1>

    <label for="mes" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Message</label>
    <input id="MessageBox" type="text">

    <label for="name" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">

    <button id="button" onclick="setMessage()" style="background: url(images/submit.png);" />

    <label for="add" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Address</label>
    <input id="add">

    <label for="pass" class="col-lg-2 control-label">Password</label>
    <input id="pass">

    <p id="status"></p>
    <button id="unlock" onclick="ButtonPress()" style="background: url(images/unlock.png);" />
</div>[![enter image description here][1]][1]
```

I have no idea about what is going wrong my buttons are being placed under my text, and are way too big.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/yARdw.png

Comment: it will be good if you can provide working demo

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The background image you are using is repeating. Add “background-repeat:no-repeat” in your style tag

Comment: That fixed the repeating, but the buttons are still gigantic and covering up the text boxes.